# Southern latitude exceeds northern latitude - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-places-autocomplete

I am using `PluginGooglePlacePicker` to show google autocomplete for addressess. But when I put location restriction to it I get this error.

```
Southern latitude exceeds northern latitude
```

It works completely fine on ios. does anyone know any workaround this?

P.S I am using flutter

thanks

Comment: Did you got any fix. Facing same issue with react native.